# Populate current user from Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am following this FilledStacks' [Youtube playlist](https://youtu.be/d6FaV7cp_YE?t=1087) and tried to update it based on the latest Firebase changes. But after adding the `_populateCurrentUser logic` logic the app froze on the startup screen. I was expecting to get the user info and get past the startup screen and navigate to home. It doesn't throw an error, it just shows the startup screen.  I have tried to double-check my code and also researched it. It returns the correct `uid` from Firestore but not sure why it isn't populating the user. Here is my code.

```
//1
var user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

//2
await _populateCurrentUser(user!);

//3
Future _populateCurrentUser(User user) async {
  _currentUser = await _firestoreService.getUser(user.uid);
}

//4
var userData = await _usersCollectionReference.doc(uid).get();

//5
UserAccountModel.fromMap(userData.data as Map<String, dynamic>);

//6
factory UserAccountModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
   UserAccountModel(
      id: json["id"] ,
      fullName: json["fullName"],
      email: json["email"],
);
```

Comment: I am not sure what is the type of ```userData``` is but I would suggest you to try this ```UserAccountModel.fromMap(userData.data());```. Putting it more generally, I am assuming you have a type mismatch or wrong way of accessing the documentSnapshot data.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. I have edited my post and edited #4 and #5.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It worked using `userData.data() as Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: I am glad it did! I'll put it as an answer to this question. so pls mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `userData.data() as Map<String, dynamic>`